# Verificar se é a class

Tags: javascript, css

Como verifico com JavaScript se é realmente aquela class no CSS?
Exemplo:

```
if(é a class) {

}
```

ou outro exemplo, se não é a class

```
if(!.minhaClasse) {

}
```

Existe algum mode de fazer isso, com JavaScript puro?

Comment: Que classe seria essa? Sua pergunta não fez muito sentido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
function contemClasse(elemento, classe) {
    for (int i = 0; i < elemento.classList.length; i++) {
        if (elemento.classList[i] == classe) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

E para usar:

```
contemClasse(foo, "nomeDaClasse");
```

Comment: Só quero com JavaScript puro porque estou estudando, Renan. Não é pra uso nenhum não.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho então eu retiro o que eu disse. Nesse caso é bom saber como as coisas são feitas.

Comment: Ta bom, obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: @Renan concordo com que havia dito. +1 na sua resposta

Comment: Lucas, eu peço desculpas pela minha agressividade ontem. Hoje eu tava revendo meus favoritos aqui no navegador e encontrei um site que pode ser interessante pra você. [You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/). Ele mostra várias das principais funcionalidades do jQuery, lado a lado com um código em Javascript puro que faz exatamente a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 6):

Com javascript puro você pode fazer assim:

```
<div id="teste" class="teste2"> Teste </div>
<script>
    var div = document.getElementById('teste');
    console.log(div.classList.contains('teste2'));
</script>
```

para mais informações segue [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)